# no module _sha256 installing cellProfiler

Tags: python, sha256, hashlib

I'm trying to install cellprofiler for developpers on linux and get a "no module named _sha256" error. I looked on a few blogs to find a solutions but nothing worked, can someone help me to fix this?

here's my configuration :

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
```

linux :

```
uname -m
i686

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

and here is the error I get:

```
local@pc-ellenberg23:~/Softwares/cellProfiler/CellProfiler$ make -f Makefile.CP2 PREFIX="${HOME}/usr/cp2"
All pre-checks executed successfully.
export PATH="/home/local/usr/cp2/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin" && \
                    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/local/usr/cp2/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" && \
                    sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg --prefix="/home/local/usr/cp2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/local/Softwares/cellProfiler/CellProfiler/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "/home/local/Softwares/cellProfiler/CellProfiler/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/setuptools/package_index.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/local/usr/cp2/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 93, in <module>
    import hashlib
  File "/home/local/usr/cp2/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
    sha224 = __get_builtin_constructor('sha224')
  File "/home/local/usr/cp2/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py", line 66, in __get_builtin_constructor
    import _sha256
ImportError: No module named _sha256
make: *** [/home/local/usr/cp2/bin/easy_install] Error 1
```

sorry if the error seems silly, i'm new on dealing with error message on linux installations

Thanks you very much

Comment: Your traceback indicates you are using Python 2.6, not 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally installed it manually, without using their makefile (installing all the dependencies, and executing the cellprofiler.py file. I had to change their code a litle bit (they use the system environment variable and it produces an error (searching my libjvm.so file in the wrong path(i386 instead of i686))
 It seems to generate the path for the **libjvm.so** file automatically from the java_home variable but in my case, the path created was wrong, (generated path : /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/**i686**/server/libjvm.so and the real path was: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/**i386**/server/libjvm.so)
hope this will help if someone has the same problem.
Please let me know if someone found the solution for the _sha256 error.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a library dependency for the `hashlib` module.

On Ubuntu, you need to install the `libsasl2-dev` and `libssl-dev` packages, then recompile (`make -f Makefile.CP2 clean; make -f Makefile.CP2 PREFIX="${HOME}/usr/cp2"`
) the `CellProfiler` dependencies.

Comment: excuse me but can you be more specific? I tried to install libsasl2-dev but it's "already up-to-date" I didn't make any `./configure`, I followed the installation guide on the cellprofiler's website [https://github.com/CellProfiler/CellProfiler/wiki/CellProfiler-Developer%27s-version-installation-for-Linux] .  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see that `CellProfiler` creates the Python binary; I'm not familiar with how their Makefile drives the Python installation, but the Python installation should have found `libsasl2-dev` already. You can also try to add `libssl-dev` (both are needed here, I thought the latter was pulling in by the former). I've updated my answer based on a quick scan of the `CellProfiler` makefile.

Comment: it seems to still not works. I prevent you when I found what's the error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: hi, I finally installed it manually, without using their makefile (installing all the dependencies, and executing the cellprofiler.py file. I had to change their code a litle bit (they use the system environment variable and it produces an error (searching my ljvm.so file in the wrong path(i386 instead of i686))

Comment: Glad you managed to solve it! You may want to add your solution as an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I own you another beer (on top of the promised brewery), or better have a look at your wishlist, soon. You just saved my day, thanks!